# Calculated column based on the MAX date per category?

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I am trying to make a calculated column in Power BI to return the last Job Title held for the name listed based on the maximum/latest date.

```
Current Title =
VAR MaxDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Date] )
    )
VAR EEID =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Employee] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        FIRSTNONBLANK (
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                FILTER (
                    'Terms FY23',
                    'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Date] = MaxDate
                        && 'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Employee] = EEID
                ),
                "JobTitle", 'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Title]
            ),
            _MaxDate
        )
    )
```

I tried this but it returned the same exact Job Title column.

| Date | Full Name | Job Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/31/2022 | John Adams | Landscaper I |
| 11/30/2022 | John Adams | Crew Leader |
| 12/31/2022 | John Adams | Crew Leader |
| 1/31/2023 | John Adams | Crew Leader |
| 2/15/2023 | John Adams | Crew Leader |

Comment: Hi Mark - please provide your sample data in copiable format.

Comment: Hi David, added.

Answer (score 0):

For you sample data this one works

```
Last Job Title = 
VAR MAXDATE = 
    MAXX('Table', 'Table'[Date])
RETURN   
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Table'[Job Title]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('Table'),
            'Table'[Date] = MAXDATE
        )
    )
```

Comment: This should work but I forgot to mention that this need to be specific to the Employee as there are multiples in that table.

Comment: Based on this comment, you should perhaps have provided a better data sample @Mark.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have more than one distinct name in the table can go via this

**calculated table**

```
Lookup Table = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Full Name],
    "Last Job Titel", CALCULATE(
        MIN('Table'[Job Title]),
        'Table'[Date] = MAX('Table'[Date])
    )
)
```

to end up with this **calulated column**

```
Last Job Title= 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    'Lookup Table'[Last Job Titel], 
    'Lookup Table'[Full Name], 'Table'[Full Name]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a calculated column that does this directly using the new `INDEX` windowing function as a filter argument, that uses `ALLEXCEPT` on your table to provide the correct row context:

```
Last Title =
CALCULATE (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Title] ),
    INDEX (
        1,
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Terms FY23', 'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Name] ),
        ORDERBY ( [Employee History.Date], DESC )
    )
)
```

This type of calculation would normally require to store the maximum date value first, and then solve for the title:

```
Last Title Old =
VAR _max_date =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Terms FY23', 'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Name] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Title] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Terms FY23', 'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Name] ),
        'Terms FY23'[Employee History.Date] = _max_date
    )
```

NB! If you have two people in this table with the same name, you are out of luck. You would need a more robust way of handling employees, for example by using a unique employee ID instead of some arbitrary name.

Comment: Appreciate the response Marcus. But it’s returning a circular dependency error.

Comment: Is this the only calculated column you have added to the table or do you have multiple?